# Basic Auth works on the browser but doesn't return anything in Postman

Tags: spring-boot, postman, basic-authentication

I have set basic auth in spring boot, when I try to access the web application using the browser by (entering localhost:8081/api/users) it directs me to the default login page generated by spring boot, then if the credentials were correct it re-directs me to localhost:8081/api/users and displays all the users.

But if I wanted to do the same thing in Postman it gives me a 200Ok and returns the html file in the body!!. I have set the autherization to basic auth and entered the right credintials but nothing seems to work on postman !!

Comment: I suggest you capture the traffic in Fiddler and compare the traffic, line by line, looking for differences.

Comment: Can you show also the security configuration?